# How to compare two entities by one of their attributes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So basically I'm doing a minecraft datapack for my server, but being really new to that I'm stuck on a problem and I don't know how to solve it:

I've got this line detecting if there is an item frame containing a leather helmet, and then executes a command:

```
execute as @s if entity @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_helmet"}}] run command
```

And the caller of the command, the `@s` is another item_frame, a leather_boots, but with a certain coloration.

So what I would like to do is to take the color into account in my `execute` line: I'd like to test if the `@s` entity's color is the same than the `@e`'s one...

It would look like that so I'm sure you understand :

```
execute as @s if entity @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",tag:{display:{color=<@s_Color>}}}}] run command
```

With `<@s_Color>` being the color of `@s`

Maybe I could achieve this by storing the color of `@s` in the first place? But then again, I'm just a beginner with minecraft commands and don't know if it is possible...

I searched all over the internet but didn't found something similar.

**Edit**: I'm using colored leather armors because it offers me a high number of variations so I have many [boots - helmets] pairs in order to do what I need. But there could be another way, maybe with a specific block or a named entity? Anyway, I would need a way to compare them

Comment: `execute as @s` does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the NBT field in a scoreboard with `execute store` and `data get`, then subtract one from the other and check for 0.

Comment: So it would look like this?

`execute as @s store result score @s NBT_score run data get entity @s`

But then, if I store the nbt of @s, it won't be the same as the one of @e, because the items IDs are different, no?

Comment: You need to add the NBT path for the colour at the end. Should I write a complete answer? I only wrote down the idea, because I seemed to already know commands well.